# How can I make React dev tools work locally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

How can I get React developer tools to work when I am developing on my local machine on the front-end only.

By front end, I mean I am loading an index.html with no server that I will later push to GitHub pages which are "static" sites.

I am getting this:

[image]

When I do push to GitHub the tools work fine when I open up in Google Chrome.

Why the difference and how do I fix it?

Obviously I have the tools installed and they work fine when I develop on the GitHub page.

Comment: It is like a `plugin` and could be found in `Chrome Web Extensions`

Comment: I have installed the plugin which works on remote hosts but not local hosts.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

1. Chrome Extensions > React Developer Tools > Manage Extensions > Allow access to file URLS (enable this).
2. Reload the page.
3. Reopen Developer Tools.

source: https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/main/packages/react-devtools#the-react-tab-doesnt-show-up

Answer (score 0):

Answering this part "You might need to use a local HTTP server":

Supposing that you have a static files for a react app. You can use 
[Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en)
and choose the folder where you have your index.html file.

Another option mentioned here [Deployment
 - Static Server](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#static-server) is to run:

`npm install -g serve`

`serve -s build` where build is the folder where your index.html file exists.

Comment: Can you format your answers to put the URLs as links with a descriptive title and context.  The URLs run across multiple lines and are hard to read.

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting. I tried to improve it. Does it look better now?

Answer (score 0):

If you run react app locally you have to

1. Install "react-devtools" (bcz chrome will not deduct it is a React App when you run in local)

   `npm install -g react-devtools`
2. And add "React Developer Tools" extension to chrome

Answer (score 0):

I just had to actually refresh the page for my local app for it to work.